# upload or share a video to Youtube from my app iOS SDK

Tags: ios, video, youtube, share, uidocumentinteraction

I'm using UIDocumentInteractionController to be able to share a video,
by using "presentOptionMenuFromRect" command a few apps are offered for a share but not Youtube.

I have Youtube installed on my iPhone.

When saving the same video to Camera roll(by the same UIDocumentInteractionController), Youtube does appear as a share option (so file type is supported by Youtube app).

Any help? 
Thanks!!!